# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, androidx

```
2019-03-14 17:55:30.897 21311-21311/com.cavidel.tradefi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cavidel.tradefi, PID: 21311
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cavidel.tradefi/com.cavidel.tradefi.ui.login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2884)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1614)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getTargetSdk(FragmentManager.java:2951)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2940)
    at android.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:82)
    at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:6965)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2739)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2884) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1614) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

2019-03-14 17:55:34.485 21311-21376/com.cavidel.tradefi D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: get result from proxy gai_error = 0
2019-03-14 17:55:34.491 21311-21376/com.cavidel.tradefi I/System.out: port:443
2019-03-14 17:55:34.900 21311-21311/com.cavidel.tradefi E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:321)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:301)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:42)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1955)

Comment: I got these error after i switch androidX. I don't know if it has anything to do with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @TamirAbutbul it's not a duplicate of NullPointerException. This has to do with using AndroidX in my app. Everything was okay before i switch to androidX